# Rank of concatenation of two full row rank matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, block-matrices

Let

$$ C_{a\times (b+c)} := \begin{bmatrix} A_{a\times b} & B_{a\times c} \end{bmatrix} $$

where matrices $A$ and $B$ are full row rank, i.e., $\mbox{rank}(A) = \mbox{rank} (B) = a$. What is the rank of $C$?

I assume $\mbox{rank} (C)=a$, but I cannot find a proof for this.

Answer (score -1):

Can the rank of $C$ be less than $a$, given that both $A$ and $B$ have rank $a$?  Can the rank of a matrix be greater than the number of its rows?  Answering these questions should help you answer yours.

Comment: The rank of a matrix define the number of linear independent rows. So, the rank of a matrix cannot be greater than the number of rows.

Comment: Concerning the first question, the rank of C is the maximum rank of A or B since any row which contains an independent row of A or B is also independent in C. If A and B have rank a then also C has rank a. So the answer is that the rank of C cannot be less than a.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by independent row?  Every nonzero row on its own is independent, but when you take two or more rows together, you might no longer have an independent set of rows.

Comment: Each row in A and B is linearly independent, due to the full rank. Maybe I should have noted that A and B have different variables. Concatenated row in A(x1,x2) and B(x3,x4) means in this case that I concatenate all columns of row x in A and B, e.g. A[3x1+x2=0] B[2x3+x4=0] -> C[3x1+x2+2x3+x4=0]. I hope this helps.

Comment: Instead of saying "Each row in $A$ and $B$ is linearly independent," it would be better to say something like "the rows of $A$ form a linearly independent set, as do the rows of $B$," because a nonzero vector is *always* linearly independent, even if it's a member of a linearly dependent set.  The distinction doesn't matter as much in this case, because both $A$ and $B$ have full rank.  But if $A$, for example, doesn't have full rank, then it does matter.